# Status of an international prospective student for a UK tourist visa

Tags: uk, tourist-visas

I have enrolled in a Canadian University for my Master’s and the course starts on the 2nd of September, I wish to visit the UK as a tourist in June but i’m unsure of my status on the ‘What are you currently doing section.’ Their options are:

- employed
- self employed
- retired
- unemployed
- student

Naturally, I assumed that I was a student but when I finished the application I was required to attach a form noting my leave of absence from my course. I am unsure of what category I fall under, could you kindly tell me?

Answer (score 2):

You are a student.

Skip such document, and add a document that states that you are enrolled to a Canadian University, and that you will start in September.

Never lie, answer the most honest as possible. If the form seems wrong, ask here, or add a note about your interpretation.

Comment: I'm doubtful about this. A naive interpretation would say you are not a student until you start your course, and it would be better to say you were unemployed and to attach notes saying you will start a course of study in September. Do you have experience or links?

Comment: +1 I agree this makes sense otherwise during summer when not enrolled in classes should a university student be designated as unemployed?

Comment: @DJClayworth: If you are enrolled, you are a student. Student job is not 9-5 job. With both interpretation a note will help, and visa officers will interpret it correctly.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Sounds reasonable.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help! So I should write Student in the application and fill the ‘proof of leave of absence portion’ with a note stating that i’m set to begin classes in September?